# Error finding mean of a column, error term: "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA[1] NA"

Tags: r, mean

I was using this code to find the mean, it somehow worked when I ran the chunk, but when I re-ran the whole notebook, an error term came up.

```
    # What is the mean suspension rate for schools  overall?
    transform(merged_data, suspension_rate_total = as.numeric(suspension_rate_total))
    mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total,na.rm = T)
    mean(merged_data[7])

    # What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms > 100? 
    mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$farms < 100], na.rm = T)

    # What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms < 100? 
    mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$farms < 100], na.rm = T)
```

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA[1] NA
```

This is the data:

**Data**

```
structure(list(schid = c("1030642", "1030766", "1030774", "1030840", 
"1130103", "1230150"), farms = c("132", "116", "348", "406", 
"68", "130"), foster = c("2", "0", "1", "8", "1", "4"), homeless = c("14", 
"0", "8", "4", "1", "4"), migrant = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0"), ell = c("18", "12", "114", "45", "7", "4"), suspension_rate_total = c("*", 
"20", "0", "0", "95", "5"), suspension_violent = c("*", "9", 
"0", "0", "20", "2"), suspension_violent_no_injury = c("*", "6", 
"0", "0", "47", "1"), suspension_weapon = c("*", "0", "0", "0", 
"8", "0"), suspension_drug = c("*", "0", "0", "0", "9", "1"), 
    suspension_defiance = c("*", "1", "0", "0", "9", "1"), suspension_other = c("*", 
    "4", "0", "0", "2", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If we check the `str(merged_data)`, the columns are `character`, it needs to be converted to `numeric`

```
mean(as.numeric(merged_data$suspension_rate_total)[as.numeric(merged_data$farms)
                  < 100], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 95
```

When we  convert to `numeric`, there would be a warning message as there are some elements that are not numeric which gets converted to `NA`

Comment: mean(as.numeric(merged_data$suspension_rate_total)[as.numeric(merged_data$farms)
                  < 100], na.rm = TRUE).            I get this code: Error in merged_data$suspension_rate_total : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @claire_123 Based on your `dput` example, it is a `data.frame`.  This error can happen if the dataset is a `matrix`

Answer (score 0):

You again! : D

your problem re-occurred since your last question because you forgot to format your data.

```
merged_data<-apply(merged_data,2,as.numeric)
```

you should always consider your classes when working with R

run this code to check it out!

```
A_character <- "1"
a_num<-1

class(a_num)
[1] "numeric"

class(A_character)
[1] "character"

class(A_character)==class(a_num)
[1] FALSE

class(A_character)!=class(a_num)
[1] TRUE
```

also works on data.frames

```
df<- data.frame(c(1:3),c("1","2","3"))
colnames(df)<- c("numbers","not_numbers")
class(df$numbers)
class(df$not_numbers)
df$not_numbers<-as.character(df$not_numbers)
df$numbers<-as.numeric(df$numbers)
class(df$numbers)
class(df$not_numbers)
```